# HTML - cannot define correct margin

Tags: html, css

I want 2 input elements in a row with a defined width. I calculated margin and padding but it does not fit into the parent element.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLz5s6kh/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
<input class="input-text left"type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
<input class="input-text" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="surname" />

 </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
   width: 400px;
   background: lightgrey;
}

.input-text{
   width: 145px;
   padding: 0 20px;
   border: 0;
   background: grey;
 }

.left{
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/bLz5s6kh/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to eliminate white space between elements as it is also counted.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <input class="input-text left" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" /><!--
    --><input class="input-text" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="surname" />
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLz5s6kh/7/

Reference: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/bLz5s6kh/2/)

css

```
.input-text {
    width: 145px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 0;
    background: grey;
    box-sizing:border-box; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: I love border-box, but my collegues don't